# Different fonts in table of contents

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, bibliographies, acronyms

In my table of content, the fonts of "Acronyms" and "Bibliography" are different from the rest of the table of content:

[image]

I think it is because they are not chapters as the rest, but I do not know how to change it. Can anyone help me? I'm not interested in adding Acronyms or Bibliography as chapters, however, I would like them to have the same font as the chapters

```latex
\documentclass[oneside,12pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{bm}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage[a4paper, hmargin={2.8cm, 2.8cm}, vmargin={2.5cm, 2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic} % \AddToShipoutPicture
\usepackage{graphicx} % \includegraphics
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[format=plain,
            font=it]{caption}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lingmacros}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.86,0.86,0.86}
\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
\makesavenoteenv{table}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

    \newsavebox\mybox
    \newenvironment{aquote}[1]
      {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
          {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}

\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authortitle,natbib=true,backend=bibtex, maxcitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}


\usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,toc,acronym,symbols,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{NNs}{NNs}{Neural Networks}
\newacronym{MDP}{MDP}{Markov Decision Process}

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage

\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]
\printglossary

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test1}
\acrfull{NNs}
\chapter{Test2}
\acrfull{MDP}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you add them manually to the table of contents with something like addcontentsline?

Comment: No, I used:
\usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,toc,acronym,symbols,nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{Acronyms}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]
\printglossary

Comment: Does \input{\scshape Acronyms} or \input{\textsc{Acronyms}} give you the right output?

Comment: Thank you - but no. I use \input{Acronyms} because I have a file called Acronyms.tex where all acronyms are specified

Comment: Ah, of course. Silly me. :|  I was confusing it with \addcontentsline{}

Comment: The `glossaries` package has options which control the appearance in the toc. However, without some minimal code there is no way to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @campa I have added my latex code. Can you help me?

Comment: @campa can you help me? The code is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear there are a lot of conflicting issues there: `classicthesis` uses `titlesec` internally, which does not really play well with KoMa classes. `glossaries` has also issues with `classicthesis`, as far as I can tell from their documentation. At this point I'd say that you can (1) wait for someone better to provide an answer `:-)`, or (2) avoid using `classicthesis`, or (3) just put the contents line manually:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt, a4paper, footinclude=true, headinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty]{scrbook}
%                /|\
%                 |
%       Do you REALLY mean this?!
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[savewrites,nopostdot,acronym,symbols,nogroupskip,section=chapter]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{NNs}{NNs}{Neural Networks}
\newacronym{MDP}{MDP}{Markov Decision Process}

\begin{document} 
\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
\texorpdfstring{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\acronymname}}{\acronymname}%
}%
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test1}
\acrfull{NNs}
\chapter{Test2}
\acrfull{MDP}

\end{document}
```

[image]